# Variables available for doGet() function? GAS Email Approval WebApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a WebApp to automate the approval process for credit card expenses.This works, but I would like to add further finesse. I would like the return/approval email to contain information gathering for the request email, but I can't seem to access the variables created in the sending mail function in the doGet function. How do I do this?

The script/WebApp:

```
function CCDEmail(e) {
  var Explain = e.values[1];
  var Cost = e.values[2];  
  var Items = e.values[3];
  var theDate = e.values[4];
  var emailfrom = e.values[5];
  var emailto = e.values[6];

  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxnhUpURschXwP_rVFSUv673DtHcfuAvNkMTYHpBHU/dev';

  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'&reply='+emailfrom; 
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'&reply='+emailfrom;

  var html = "<body>"+
             "<h2>Please review Credit Card Expenses</h2><br />"+
             "Month:"+ theDate+ "<br />"+
             "Total Cost:"+ Cost + "<br />" + "List of items:"+ Items+ "<br />"+
             "Explanation of Other purchases:"+ Explain+ "<br />"+
             "<br />"+
             "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
             "<a href="+ reject +">Reject</a><br />"+
             "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailto, "Credit Card Declaration " +theDate, "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});  
}



function doGet(e){
  //add date and other variables from above
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved' : 'Please see me!'; 

  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Credit Card Declaration", "Your manager said: "+ answer);   
  //add send email to accounts

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + ' saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
  return app
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: You could use propertiesService to store and retrieve them: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, "Will you be calling `CCDEmail(e)` from the `doGet()`, or does the `CCDEmail(e)` function get run later and independently.

If the `CCDEmail(e)` function gets called independently from the `doGet()`, then you need a way to store the values outside of the `doGet()` function.  There are three ways to do that, 1) Cache 2) Global variables. 3) Properties

Cache is temporary, so depending on how long the interval between opening the app is, and running the `CCDEmail(e)` function, you may not want to use Cache.

Some people are vehemently opposed to using global variables, so depending upon your opinion, you may or may not want to use them.

Properties are good to use, but if you have lots of data, you may hit the limits.

Probably go with the Properties option first.

Declare and set some variables in your `doGet()` then retrieve the value in the `CCDemail()` function:

```
function doGet(e){
  //add date and other variables from above
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved' : 'Please see me!'; 

  var Explain = e.values[1];
  var Cost = e.values[2];  
  var Items = e.values[3];
  var theDate = e.values[4];
  var emailfrom = e.values[5];
  var emailto = e.values[6];

  // Set multiple script properties in one call.
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperties({
    'argExplain': Explain,
    'argCost': Cost,
    'argItems': Items'
  });



  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Credit Card Declaration", "Your manager said: "+ answer);   
  //add send email to accounts

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + ' saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
  return app
}
```

To retrieve the values:

```
function CCDEmail() {

  // Get multiple script properties in one call, then log them all.
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();

  var Explain = data['argExplain'];
  var Cost = data['argCost'];  
  var Items = data['argItems'];
  var theDate = data['argtheDate'];
  var emailfrom = data['argemailfrom'];
  var emailto = data['argemailto'];

  Logger.log(data['argExplain']);

  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxnhUpURschXwP_rVFSUv673DtHcfuAvNkMTYHpBHU/dev';

  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'&reply='+emailfrom; 
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'&reply='+emailfrom;

  var html = "<body>"+
             "<h2>Please review Credit Card Expenses</h2><br />"+
             "Month:"+ theDate+ "<br />"+
             "Total Cost:"+ Cost + "<br />" + "List of items:"+ Items+ "<br />"+
             "Explanation of Other purchases:"+ Explain+ "<br />"+
             "<br />"+
             "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
             "<a href="+ reject +">Reject</a><br />"+
             "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailto, "Credit Card Declaration " +theDate, "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});  
}
```

I didn't test this code.  It probably has errors, but hopefully the basic idea of how to accomplish what you want is correct.

Comment: Sandy, many thanks, I'll give this a try.  There could be several days between the CCDEmail() and the doGet(). I wonder if there is another way by feeding the "approve" and "reject" variables with the other data variables using the CCDEmail() function so that these are fed back?